# May I travel in Schengen zone with an expired EU passport?

Tags: passport, schengen

The passport has expired 2 years ago. I want to travel by plane on a direct flight from Lisbon to Austria. I might not be able to get a new passport from my embassy on time (I'm a resident in Portugal). The only other document I have is an Austrian divers license.

Comment: I wonder if this question might be better on [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You should ask this question on [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/). On the other hand I think you are out of luck, as most airlines require passports or national IDs on international flights, even inside the Schengen Area. Driving licence is usually only valid for domestic flights. Also [read this](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm).

Comment: The question can now [be found on travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27337/may-i-travel-in-schengen-zone-with-an-expired-eu-passport)